# Data are not loaded in Edit Form in Vue app

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I'm experimenting with Vue.js and Axios with Laravel. I'm using this tutorial where a simple Posts app is build: https://pusher.com/tutorials/laravel-vue-axios. I'm trying to extend this with an Update function. When I'm clicking on the edit button near a Post, the right Id is fetched. But in my Edit form the data of the post aren't loading. What could be the issue?

This is my code in EditPost.vue:

```
<template>
    <form action="" @submit="editPost(post)">
        <h4 class="text-center font-weight-bold">Post edit form</h4>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="title" class="form-control"> {{ post.title }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea placeholder="content" class="form-control" v-model="post.content">
            </textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button :disabled="!isValid" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" @click.prevent="updatePost(post)">Update
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>

<script>

    import {mapGetters, mapActions} from 'vuex'

    export default {
        name: "EditPost",
        data() {
            return {
                post:{}
            }
        },
        created () {
            this.fetchData();
        },

        mounted() {
            this.$store.dispatch('fetchPost')
        },
        methods: {
            ...mapActions('post', [
                'fetchPost',
                'updatePost'
            ]),
            updatePost(post) {
                this.$store.dispatch('updatePost', post)
            },
            fetchData: function () {
                var _this = this;
                // ajax call - then
                _this.$store.commit('setData', {
                    name: 'post',
                    data: res.data.post
                });
            }
        },
        computed: mapGetters([
            'posts'
        ])

    }

</script>
```

This is the code in recources/js/store/actions.js:

```
fetchPost({commit}, post) {
    axios.get(`/api/posts/${post.id}`)
        .then(res => {
            commit('FETCH_POST', res.data)
        }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
},
```

**UPDATE**: I've put in extra code.

file Posts.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h4 class="text-center font-weight-bold">Posts</h4>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Title</th>
                <th scope="col">Content</th>
                <th scope="col">Actions</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr v-for="post in posts">
                <td>{{post.title}}</td>
                <td>{{post.content}}</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-info" @click="editPost(post)"><i style="color:white" class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" @click="deletePost(post)"><i style="color:white" class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
    import {mapGetters} from 'vuex'

    export default {
        name: "Posts",
        mounted() {
            this.$store.dispatch('fetchPosts')
        },
        methods: {
            editPost(post) {
                this.$store.dispatch('fetchPost',post)
            },
            deletePost(post) {
                this.$store.dispatch('deletePost',post)
            }
        },
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters([
                'posts'
            ])
        }
    }
</script>
```

file recources/js/store/getters.js:

```
let getters = {
     posts: state => {
         return state.posts
     }
}

export default getters
```

file recources/js/store/state.js:

```
let state = {
    posts: []
}

export default state
```

file recources/js/store/mutations.js:

```
let mutations = {
    CREATE_POST(state, post) {
        state.posts.unshift(post)
    },
    FETCH_POSTS(state, posts) {
        return state.posts = posts
    },
    UPDATE_POST(state, post) {
        let index = state.posts.findIndex(item => item.id === post.id)
    },
    DELETE_POST(state, post) {
        let index = state.posts.findIndex(item => item.id === post.id)
        state.posts.splice(index, 1)
    }
}
export default mutations
```

Comment: fyi, `<input type="text"...` uses a `value=` attribute to set/get its value, writing the title after the input will get you nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `post.content`, which is coming from your data prop `post`. I don't see you adding content to `post` anywhere in your code.

I'm assuming your getter `posts` is getting the post data from the store.

So maybe you just need to use that instead?

```
v-model="posts.content">
```

Without seeing more of your code I cannot tell you exactly what to do. But your main problem is after you update the store value you need to get that value somehow.

Comment: v-model="posts.content" doesn't work even. I've put extra code in the initial post. Hope that this will give you more relevant info.